# More Readability by removing the grid background

Tags: discussion

The graphic design section for Stack Exchange has this grid background that makes reading questions and answers difficult. I think a plain white background would be much better in place of the grid background.

Being a graphic designer and programmer I find Stack Overflow more pleasing to use and graphically cleaner.

Comment: Related:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5th of the [7 essential meta questions of every beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is "what should our logo and site design look like?".  I suggest you get started on those :)

What you see right now is the "sketchy" theme -- we use it for sites that don't yet have their own look-and-feel (something typically added at graduation from beta).  It's not unique to graphicdesign.SE, so we're not going to do a bunch of custom tweaking.  Instead, put your time into deciding what your permanent theme should be like.

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of that I had only ever seen this design used here on the graphic design theme.